# error while initializing marionette driver

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-marionette, geckodriver

I am using `Selenium` webdriver for testing application. I have `firefox 48.0.1` installed `windows 10 64 bit`. I am using `Marionette` driver for application testing. However when I have mentioned :

```
WebDriver driver=new MarionetterDriver();
```

it gives the error :

> Marionette driver cannot resolve to a type.

For the same, I have set

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\ashwini\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the reply,
issue is resolved by adding selenium server standalone jar into the project. I have downloaded the latest jar of it n was able to import "org.openqa.selenium.firefox.MarionetteDriver"

Answer (score 0):

This issue is may be because you are trying to run code that doesn't compile properly. Try checking for compilation errors before running your app. If you are sure its not a compilation issue *try reconfiguring Eclipse with selenium 2*

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the wrong WebDriver. You must initialize FirefoxDriver as:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

If you are using Selenium Standalone jar version 3.0.0-beta then no need to pass marionette in capabilities. If you are using Selenium Standalone jar less than 3.0.0-beta then you need to pass marionette as capabilities and initialize FirefoxDriver as follows:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Tried with geckodriver v 0.10.0. Hope this helps.